# How to define Table Structure while migrating csv from S3 to RDS using AWS Database Migration Service

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration

I have a `csv` file in my `S3` bucket and I want to migrate a content of the csv to `RDS PostgresSQL db`. For that purpose I'm trying to use `AWS Database Migration Service` and had no problem with filling in all fields except one which is `Table Structure`. I don't know how exactly should the `json` look like for the table structure and I couldn't find anything about it in AWS documentation.

[image]

My csv file has around 300 fields both string and numeric and I have also created a table in the db for the csv. Is there a smart way to generate a json for the Table structure?